# Using for-loop to add numbers together

Tags: ruby, for-loop, numbers

If I randomly put in two numbers (first number is smaller), how do I use a for-loop to add all the numbers between and itself?

ex:
first number: 3

second number: 5

the computer should give an answer of '12'.

How do I do that using a for-loop?

Comment: why do you need a for loop for that? Can you explain what you trying accomplish ?

Comment: For example.... first number is 3 second number is 5 the computer should add 3+4+5 = 12

Comment: i want to do it in a for-loop

Comment: dont use a for loop. turn your range into an enumerable, and call inject. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple for loop across the range you defined:

```
puts "Enter first number: "
first = gets.to_i
puts "Enter second number: "
second = gets.to_i

total = 0
for i in (first..second) do
  total += i
end

puts total
```

Note that if you don't enter a valid number, it will converted to 0. Also this assumes the second number is larger than the first.

Comment: This gives the total of the numbers added not the numbers between.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby we *seldom* use a `for` loop because it leaves litter behind. Instead, you can very simply do what you want using `inject`:

```
(3..5).inject(:+) # => 12
```

This is using some of the deeper Ruby magic (`:+`), which is a symbol for the `+` method and is passed into `inject`. How it works is a different question and is something you'll need to learn later.

Don't insist on doing something in a language using a particular construct you learned in another language. That will often force non-idiomatic code and will keep you from learning how to do it as other programmers in that language would do it. That creates maintenance issues and makes you less desirable in the workplace.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, or in plain-vanilla Ruby with ActiveSupport, you can do something even simpler than a for loop, or than what other people wrote.

```
(first_num..second_num).sum
```

This is shorthand for sum in Ruby:

```
sum = 0
(first_num..second_num).each { |num| sum += num }
```

Comment: Not without Active_Support

Comment: The `sum`method has been promoted to plain Ruby, so my previous comment is no longer true.

Answer (score 2):

```
first, second = [3,5]
for x in (0..0) do
  p (first + second)*(second - first + 1) / 2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you said `for` loop, but why not use what Ruby gives you?

```
> a = 3
> b = 5
> a.upto(b).inject(0) {|m,o| m += o}
=> 12
```

If you insist on a `for` loop...

```
> m = 0
=> 0
> for i in 3..5
*   m += i
* end
=> 3..5
> m
=> 12
```

Comment: 3 to 5 = 12 is just an example

Comment: i want to put two numbers randomly

Comment: @YahsHef I've updated it to make it clear that this works for any set of numbers.

Comment: fyi you can just inject `:+` eg. `3.upto(5).inject(&:+)`

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby 2.4 you directly call `sum` on an Enumerable.

For Example `[1, 2, 3].sum   #=> 6`

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby it's very rare to see a `for` loop. In this instance a more idiomatic method would be [`upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto):

```
x = 3
y = 5
total = 0

x.upto(y) do |n|
  total += n
end

puts total
# => 12
```

Another method would be to use [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
total = x.upto(y).reduce do |sum, n|
  sum += n
end
```

...which can be shortened to this:

```
total = x.upto(y).reduce(&:+)
```